# how to find the limit of this function?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

$f(x,y)= \frac{( 1+ x^2 y^2)^{1/3} -  1}{x^2 + y^2}$  for $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$

〖Lim〗_((x,y)→(0,0) ) f(x,y)

I have tried many paths but the limit is becoming $1/0$.
so what is the solution to this problem?

does the limit exist? if yes what is its value?

i have substituted y = mx^n
and cross checked it for many values of m and n.

Comment: I guess that you're looking for the limit when $(x,y)\to 0$, right ? Please show exactly what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polar coordinates:

$$x=r\cos t\;\;,\;\;y=r\sin t\;\;,\;\text{so:}$$

$$\frac{(1+x^2y^2)^{1/3}-1}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{\left(1+r^2\cos^2t\sin^2t\right)^{1/3}-1}{r^2}\stackrel{(*)}=$$

$$=\frac{1+r^2\cos^2t\sin^2t-1}{r^2\left[\left(1+r^2\cos^2t\sin^2t\right)^{2/3}+\left(1+r^2\cos^2t\sin^2t\right)^{1/3}+1\right]}=$$

$$=\frac{\cos^2t\sin^2t}{\left(1+r^2\cos^2t\sin^2t\right)^{2/3}+\left(1+r^2\cos^2t\sin^2t\right)^{1/3}+1}\xrightarrow[r\to 0]{}\frac{\cos^2t\sin^2t}{3}$$

and since the above clearly depends on the angle $\;t\;$ the limit doesn't exist.

(*) is based on the formula

$$a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)\iff a-b=\frac{a^3-b^3}{a^2+ab+b^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

If you have paths wich give you $1/0$, then try the a path with $x=0$, which gives you as limit $0$ (the function is 0 on the two axis). If for any other path you have something different it means the function is not continuous at the origin.